# Adding an incremental number for an uploaded file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I need to add an incremental number at the end of the file every time I upload a file. I go it almost working.

Please check the following code:

```
Dim intVersion As Integer = 1
   While (System.IO.File.Exists(strDestinationPath))
       Dim temp As Integer = ourFilename.LastIndexOf(".")
       Dim temp2 As String = ourFilename.Substring(temp)
       ourFilename = ourFilename.Replace(temp2, "_" & intVersion & temp2)
       strDestinationPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebLocalContentDir") & "\VisualID\" & ourFilename
       intVersion += 1
   End While
```

If I upload the file 3 times, it saves as,

1st time: VDFGH
2nd time: VDFGH_1
3rd time: VDFGH_1_2 (Expected output is VDFGH_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim intVersion As Integer = 1
While (System.IO.File.Exists(strDestinationPath))
   Dim temp As Integer = ourFilename.LastIndexOf(".")
   Dim temp2 As String = ourFilename.Substring(temp)
   dim tempFileName as string = ourFilename.Replace(temp2, "_" & intVersion & temp2)
   strDestinationPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebLocalContentDir") & "\VisualID\" & tempFileName
   intVersion += 1
End While
```

Pretty sure that this would work. You were changing your original file name string and then modifying that every time.